# Remove UILabel from UIView Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, uilabel

I am adding some labels on a UIScrollView and getting their text from a NSMutableArray:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!

    let containerView = UIView()
    var array = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       // containerView.frame = myScrollView.frame

         array = ["some text", "some other text", "text 3and 4 loremnd 4 lorem ips ipsum", "more text", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam", "quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in", "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident", "sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"]

        self.update()


    }


    @IBAction func addSomething(sender: AnyObject) {

        array.addObject("this is at the end")

       self.update()
    }

    @IBAction func removeSomething(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.containerView.removeFromSuperview() //this doesn't work
        array.removeLastObject()

         self.update()

    }


    func update() {


        for i  in 0...array.count - 1 {

            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, CGFloat(i) * 74 + 20, 64, 64))
            label.text = array[i] as? String

            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
            label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.4
            label.layer.masksToBounds = true
            label.layer.cornerRadius = 32
            label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor
            label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

            self.containerView.addSubview(label)


        }

        self.myScrollView.contentSize.height = CGFloat(array.count) * 78
        myScrollView.addSubview(containerView)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }





}
```

My problem is that Although I can remove the last object from my array when I call the `removeSomething function` the last label is still on my view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you clear `self.containerView` before call `self.update()`.  I bet you call update multiple times and there are several labels at the same places.

Try clear containerView at the beginning of update():

```
func update() {
    containerView.removeFromSuperview() // Clear containerView
    containerView = UIView() // Create a new instance

    for i  in 0...array.count - 1 {

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, CGFloat(i) * 74 + 20, 64, 64))
        label.text = array[i] as? String

        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.4
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        self.containerView.addSubview(label)


    }

    self.myScrollView.contentSize.height = CGFloat(array.count) * 78
    myScrollView.addSubview(containerView)


}
```

Comment: I have added that to my remove function but still the same. self.containerView.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: I have just updated it. plus update() is only called once. This is all my code by the way...

Comment: Thanks mate..I don't understand why it didn't work in my removeSomething function. BUT MANY THANKS!

Comment: I guess you are using a strong reference to containerView, it won't be nil after you call removeFromSuperview.  So you just keep adding labels to the same containerView instance.